# Why does open world game create/destroy objects constantly but it still runs smoothly?

Tags: unity-game-engine, memory-management

I've been taught that constantly creating & destroying objects will heavily affect performance (That's why I use object-pooling to prevent this). But an open world game does not only create & destroy objects (RAM), but it also loads & unloads assets from disc, and it still runs smoothly.

This question is not about how to make an open world game (too broad, I think), but about what API in Unity should I look into to create/destroy object, load/unload asset for open world game.

I create object with `Object.Instantiate()` & destroy with `Object.Destroy()`. I hear about the API's `Application.LoadLevelAdditiveAsync()` can make open world possible, but I still don't understand about the creating & destroying objects without affecting performance.

Comment: well you can use `LoadLevelAdditiveAsync` also for loading a sinlge object if the loaded scene only contains that object .. it sounds kind of hacky but maybe it works smoother than instantiate them ^^

Comment: Anyway note that "run smoothly" allways depends a lot on your device setup .. it might not on a weaker setup

Comment: @derHugo - right, but assume you have a good enough PC (which can run GTA Vice City smoothly)

Comment: ^^ GTA Vice City is not a good indicator for a "good enough PC" .. try to run GTA V on it e.g. this is a whole other level ^^

Comment: See also: threads

Answer (score 0):

You are adviced not to create gameobjects too often for the sake of the engine having to do extra work in the background that impacts the framerate on mobile devices. However if you are on a desktop, and have some performance headroom, there isn't any reason why you woulnd't create objects on every frame if you wish.

As for open worlds - the object creation / dectruction only happens once in a while, not per frame, so the overall performance impact doesn't have to that large (especially if your PC is up to date)